# Preventing page break between a Verbatim environment and an equation

Tags: page-breaking, fancyvrb

I have a document in which displayed equations often appear immediately after an environment created using the [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package. How can I prevent page breaks from appearing in between?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\},}
\begin{document}
\rule{1pt}{467pt}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\begin{code}
Int( x^2 , x ) ;
\end{code}
% *** Don't break here! ***
\begin{equation*}
\int x^2 \, \mathrm{d} x
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `code` environment does `\penalty\@envparpenalty` at the end, the usual value is –51, which allows (actually prefers) a page break.

Define `code` to issue a “no break penalty”.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{code}
 {\@endparpenalty=\@M\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
 {\end{Verbatim}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to forbid a break if and only if the next item is a displayed formula? (My thinking is that if the `\@envparpenalty` were to be removed altogether, then the `\predisplaypenalty` would do the job, but I might be wrong.)

Comment: @IanThompson I don't think so; glue is also added: LaTeX lists are wild beasts, I'm afraid.

Comment: ok, I'll just define a separate environment for the minority of cases in which an example code isn't followed by a displayed formula.

Answer (score 1):

Does this suffice?  I surround the unbreakable stuff with a `\setbox0=\vbox{`...`}\box0`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\},}
\usepackage{needspace}
\begin{document}
\rule{1pt}{467pt}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\setbox0=\vbox{%
\begin{code}
Int( x^2 , x &%$$\{\}[])^&#  ;
\end{code}
% *** Don't break here! ***
\begin{equation*}
\int x^2 \, \mathrm{d} x
\end{equation*}
}\box0
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would work, but it would be awkward in cases where there is more than one line of code (breaks between lines of code are ok; I just don't want the result orphaned on the next page). I should probably clarify the question.